# Traceback error: Django dictionary

Tags: python, django, facebook

I was testing out the facebook SDK on a Django project and this error popped up, here's the traceback:

http://dpaste.com/3VCMYEC

Here's the urls.py pertaining to the site.

```
def facebook(request):

    '''A sample application that will publish a status update after going into the login process using the Javascript SDK '''

    yourappid = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    return render(request, 'hackathon/facebook.html', yourappid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yourappid` must be a dictionary object.

```
yourappid = XXXXXXXXXXX
return render(request, 'hackathon/facebook.html', {'id': yourappid})
```

[URL dispatcher Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/)